# TLP250 schematic

Tags: power-electronics

I want a spice model of TLP250 to use in Lt Spice XVII. I am making a gate driver circuit for mosfet. The frequency of square wave is 100kHZ. The mosfet is STF27N60M2-EP.

[Datasheet for mosfet is here..](https://datasheet4u.com/datasheet-pdf/STMicroelectronics/STF27N60M2-EP/pdf.php?id=974394)

Comment: Welcome to SE EE. *I want a spice model...* Thanks for letting us know. Look on the manufacturer's website for a model. If it does not exist consider using a different model optoisolator which does have a simulation model.

Comment: @Bimpelrekkie Please can you suggest any???
Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The Toshiba website for the [TLP250](https://toshiba.semicon-storage.com/ap-en/product/opto/photocoupler/detail.TLP250.html) does not give a spice model. It states that this part is "Not recommended for new designs" and lists some alternatives such as the [TLP5702](https://toshiba.semicon-storage.com/ap-en/product/opto/photocoupler/detail.TLP5702.html). Toshiba claim that this is "Almost same characteristics but different package", but you will have to check that it is a suitable replacement for the TLP250 in your application. On the page for the TLP5702 there is an LtSpice model.